# Point a form to a specific controller action ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Does anyone know how to point the following comments form to the hello action in my comments controller below, any advice would be appreciated:

```
<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@venue, @venue.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

//////////////////my comments controller:

```
def hello
     @venue = Venue.find(params[:venue_id])
     @comment = @venue.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:commenter, :body))
     redirect_to venue_path(@venue)
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set route properly, for example:

```
resources :venues do
  resources :comments do
    collection do
      post :hello
    end
  end
end
```

and set form url to this action's url:

```
 <%= form_for(@venue.comments.build, url: hello_venue_comments_path(@venue)) do |f| %>
```

Comment: I get the following error when using the suggest code above: undefined method `hello_venues_comments_path' - any tips here, thanks in advance.

Comment: @Joshua please paste the output of `rake routes` into your question.

Comment: @Joshua ok, I wrote it from the top of my head and I made a mistake. I edited my answer - please try it now.